# Why I can't run the code in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

My code is:

```
lineWidth = 40
str1 = 'Content'
str2 = 'page1'
chapter1 = 'Chapter 1:  Numbers'

puts str1.center lineWidth
puts chapter1.ljust (lineWidth/2) + str2.rjust (lineWidth/2)
```

After launch in console I have an error:

```
calc.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting end-of-input
puts chapter1.ljsut (lineWidth/2) + chapter1.rjsut (lineWidth/2)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Apparently the community thinks your question could have been better reduced to a minimal problem. Who knows, in the process you may have figured out the cause. (Also, you have 'ljust' spelled wrong in your error message, which is impossible given your code, so there may be lack of trust in your code snippets)

Answer (score 7):

Remove the extra space. It should be like this:

```rb
puts chapter1.ljust(lineWidth/2) + str2.rjust(lineWidth/2)
```

Quoting [The Ruby Programming Language](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=space%20between%20function%20argument%20ruby&source=bl&ots=fJCnzb2zgE&sig=rrpRBgjWjH-V3li768I9LIJaLvM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QtEaVav0D8vHuASw3IGQCw&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=space%20between%20function%20argument%20ruby&f=false) by David Flanagan, Yukihiro Matsumoto:

> Never put a space between a method name and the opening parenthesis.